# how to show two contacts with same name but different number

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am using this bunch of code through which I am checking that if a contact have 2 numbers then they will show 2 contact with same name with different number .. but this code sometimes not get the data properly

```
self.contacts = [ABContactsHelper personalSorting];
 NSString *emailAre;
   for (int i=0; i< [self.contacts count]; i++)
    {
        ABContact *contObj = [self.contacts objectAtIndex:i];        
        if([contObj.emailDictionaries count] >=1)
            emailAre = [[contObj.emailDictionaries objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"value"];
           // emailAre = @"";
        else
            emailAre = @"";
        for (int j=0; j< [contObj.phoneDictionaries  count]; j++) 
        {
            if([contObj.phoneDictionaries count] != 0)
            {
                if([[contObj.phoneDictionaries objectAtIndex:j] count] >= 1)
                {
                    NSLog(@"***************************************");
                    NSLog(@"contact Name %@",contObj.firstname);
                    NSLog(@"contact Number %@",[[contObj.phoneDictionaries objectAtIndex:j]objectForKey:@"value"]);
                    NSLog(@"***************************************");

                    NSString *phones = [[contObj.phoneDictionaries objectAtIndex:j]objectForKey:@"value"];

                    CFErrorRef  anError = NULL;
                    ABRecordRef aRecord = ABPersonCreate(); 
                    // Set the record values
                    ABRecordSetValue(aRecord, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, 
                                     contObj.firstname, &anError); 

                     ABMutableMultiValueRef multiTelephone = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
                     ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiTelephone, phones, kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, NULL);

                     ABRecordSetValue(aRecord, kABPersonPhoneProperty, multiTelephone, &anError);

                    /// Image
                    NSData *dataRef = UIImagePNGRepresentation(contObj.image);

                    ABPersonSetImageData(aRecord, (CFDataRef)dataRef, &anError);
                    /// Image

                     ABMutableMultiValueRef multiEmail = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);

                     ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiEmail, emailAre, kABWorkLabel, NULL);

                     ABRecordSetValue(aRecord, kABPersonEmailProperty, multiEmail, &anError);

                     ABContact *newContract = [ABContact contactWithRecord:aRecord]; 

                    [dup addObject:newContract];
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Retrieve address book data in same way you are retrieving it.  Then
2. Make a array of contacts (with dictionary of name and contact no in it)
3. Add each contact no in separate index with repeating user name data
4. Now populate this contact data in `tableView`